# How can I invalidate flow layout with animation like in ios?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm making an app in Xcode for Mojave OSX.

I want to make a resize of a `collectionview` and items position of that.
Currently I call to `invalidateLayout()` method, but it recalculate and set sizes and positions without animations.

[image]

In the GIF you could see what is the current behavior, I need that the last item go to second `row`, in an animated way.

For this i try to override this methods of `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
  open override func prepare(forAnimatedBoundsChange oldBounds: NSRect){


    }

    open override func finalizeAnimatedBoundsChange() {

    }
```

But these never get called, and I don't know what code I need to animate this transition.

Answer (score 0):

(Moved from question to an answer.)

You could override the viewDidLayout of your viewController (or assign an observer to the frame view) and execute this:

```
 collectionView.animator().performBatchUpdates(nil)
```

This reloads your collectionviewLayout with an animation.